# Make Excel file using PHPExcel and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have this AJAX function to send data to PHPExcel :

```
$("#btn_excel").on('click',function(e){
        var test    = "This is my Var";

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/excel_pembebanan'); ?>",
                cache: false,
                data: test,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    window.open('<?php echo site_url('con_atk/excel_pembebanan'); ?>','_blank');
                }
        });
});
```

This is my controller:

```
public function excel_pembebanan()
    {      
        $this->load->library('Excel');

        $val = $this->input->post('data');

        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Laporan Pembebanan');


        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $val );
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(20);


        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $filename= "cabe.xls'"; 
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); 
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
```

The code is successfully generating excel file. But the value written in the cell is "FALSE". The value should be "This is my Var".

What's wrong in the code? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all check $val = $this->input->post('data'); does $val contains any value in it or not?

Comment: It should be `data: { 'data' : test },` in the way you expect it, I think.

Comment: @Mayank: is there easy way to check $val in controller?

Comment: Just make an echo $val and exit.

Comment: @MayankPandey : I think it's empty. but why?

Comment: check in your ajax call whether it is passed or not ?

Comment: It's succeed opening a new page. It should be passed, right?

Comment: If it is passing successfully than you can use it.

Comment: When using input, the return is false if no data is found. 
Doublecheck that data with error_log($_POST["data"]); error_log($val); right after getting the val from the input and then check your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old question so you may have already solved it but from looking at the code it looks like your expecting your post array to contain a field called data yet you haven't uploaded anything with that name. Your entire posted content just consists of the phrase "This is my Var" so there's no name to refer to it by at all. if you don't want to tidy us the way you're sending your data then try amending:

```
$val = $this->input->post('data');
```

to:

```
$val = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

this will give you the raw posted data which should just be the string you've sent. If you'd prefer something a little tidier then changing your AJAX call to:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/excel_pembebanan'); ?>",
                cache: false,
                data: { 'data' : test },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(response)
                {
                    window.open('<?php echo site_url('con_atk/excel_pembebanan'); ?>','_blank');
                }
        });
```

and then making the $val assignment in your controller read:

```
$val = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
```

would then mean that you can write to the cell with:

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $val['data'] );
```